# Erro com testes em Registro/Autenticação React

Tags: react, testes-de-unidade

Estou trabalhando numa aplicação, em que os testes já estão definidos. Após a implementação estou tendo alguns erros como:

src/tests/HomePage.test.js
  ● **Test HomePage component › uses Router for logout functionality**

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(HomePage)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(HomePage)".
```

src/App.test.js
  ● **Test AppComponent › check route, dispatch and store setup for component**

```
Given action "USERS_LOGOUT", reducer "authentication" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hol
```

d no value, you can return null instead of undefined.

**Test AppComponent › check for redirections**

```
Given action "USERS_LOGOUT", reducer "authentication" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hol
```

d no value, you can return null instead of undefined.

Test AppComponent
    **✕ check route, dispatch and store setup for component (57ms)

    ✕ check for redirections (4ms)**

Alguém pode me dar uma sugestão?

Código fonte:
[github.com/dropecosta/react-redux-authentication](https://github.com/dropecosta/react-redux-authentication)

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Esse teste src/tests/HomePage.test.js está falhando por que se ta fazendo um teste em componente connect com o redux mas não ta passando a Store, acredito que se você fizer algo assim o teste irá passar.

```
<Provider store={mockStore}>
    <HomePage />
</Provider>
```

Agora os outros dois testes acredito que esteja dando problema por falta de dado na store, porém não consigo ter certeza disso.